# Regex for differentiate end of the words "regulatory" "regulatories" (begins "regulator" / ends "y" OR "ies")

Tags: regex

When I need to search for either "regulatory" or "regulatories" I use

\bregulatory\b|\bregulatories\b

Is there any way I could create a Regex considering the word beginning as same and just consider the different ends "y" OR "ies" but not any other. I mean, I could use:

\bregulator.{0,3}\b

but it could mismatch 'regulatorial'.

So, I am looking for something like that: \bregulator.{y OR ies}\b  (it doesn't exist in Regex and it is exactly how to translate it to regex what I am looking for).

Comment: `|` is a simple “or” in regex, so something like `\bregulator(y|ies)\b` should be what you’re looking for.

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: @user3570996: Welcome to Stack Overrflow! Please consider bookmarking  our [Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
\bregulator(?:y|ies)\b
```

Update based on your comment:

```
\bregulator(?:y|ies|s)\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/gJ6nD4

Comment: `?:` is just a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - it's not necessary here.

Comment: Thanks everybody! An additional point. If it was just an "s" in the end of a word, which could exists or not. E.g. regulator|regulators. Often I use regulator.? but if I know it can be only "s", I would like to consider it could have or not a character after regulator, if there is it can be only "s".

Comment: Thanks again! I know the very basic regex. The ?: is new for me. For what is it? I used the expression without it (y|ies|s) and the output where the same. So, what are the advantages of ?: thanks

Comment: ?: means that group won't be captured and the regex will perform faster, also less confusion on the output.

Comment: The `?:` in `(?:…)` is a PCRE feature.  @carloscadux: you can use `s?` to look for zero or one s's.

Answer (score 1):

> a Regex considering the word beginning as same and just consider the different ends "y" OR "ies" but not any other

Please, try with [this](http://regex101.com/r/tE4pY7) pattern:

```
\bregulator(?:y|ies)\b
```

- The `(?:y|ies)` statement to exactly what you expect. So `(?:A|B)` means `A` or `B`.

Comment: Don't forget the 'ial'

Comment: `?:` is just a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - it's not necessary here.